# Spreadsheet::WriteExcel something wrong with write_formula

Tags: perl, excel

I'm trying to write an formula using WriteExcel

```
=SUMIF(J3:J54;"=xxx";H3:H54)
```

but that code:

```
$sheet->write_formula($row+1, 0, "=SUMIF(J" . ($row-($row-3)) . ":J" . ($row-2) . ";\"=xxx\";H" . ($row-($row-3)) . ":H" . ($row-2) . ")");
```

ends with

> Unknown defined name SUMIF in formula at test.pl line 196

But when I print out that formula (using print) I got exactly the same string as wanted one (calculations on $row are good)

I'm pretty sure this code should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to us the US style union operator "," instead of the European style ";":

```
=SUMIF(J3:J54,"=xxx",H3:H54)
```

If you modifiy your formula string to replace ; with , it will work. I tested it.

Comment: Ok it's working, but when I write =SUMIF(J3:J54,A1,H3:H54) it doesn't calculate (0). I have to click on that cell in excel and press Return - then excel calculate it in right way?

Comment: store/repeat_formula doesn't help... or I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Drop me an email to the address in the S::WE docs I can send you a workaround for that using store/repeat_formula(). If you Google for it you may find it as well. However, you would be better off using Excel::Writer::XLSX which doesn't have these types of formula problems.

Comment: You said that Write::XLSX doesn't have such problems, but it does. Even with simple =SUM(A1:A3)     $sheet->write($row, 1, "=SUM(B" . ($row-2) . ":B" . ($row) . ")", $styler{rest});    it doesn't calculate but write out 0. I have to press return in excel to force calculation...

Comment: That's a different issue. Send a test case and I'll look at it.